# How to properly print error messages from `luaL_dostring()`?

Tags: error-handling, lua

Here's my code that runs a Lua script as a string.

```
bool doString(const char *s)
{
    const int ret = luaL_dostring(L, s);
    if (ret)
    {
        if (ret == LUA_ERRSYNTAX)
            printf("Error: %s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        else if (ret == LUA_ERRMEM)
            printf("Error: memory error");
        else
            printf("Error: syntax error");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But in many cases, my code just prints `Error: syntax error` without any further description about where the error is happening.

How can I properly print the error messages so it can be more descriptive?

Comment: Why the ifs? Just print `lua_tostring(L, -1)` when there are errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`luaL_dostring` returns `LUA_OK /* 0 */` on success, and `1` on failure [1]. When it fails, it will push an error message on the stack describing the problem. This can be determined by following `luaL_loadstring` to `lua_load` in the docs [2]. Also, `luaL_dostring` invokes `lua_pcall`, which also pushes an error object on the stack when it fails (with no handler set) [3]

When you get a nonzero result, you can check the top of the stack for the error message and print that:

```cpp
bool doString(const char *s) {
    const int ret = luaL_dostring(L, s);

    if (ret != LUA_OK) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
      lua_pop(L, 1); // pop error message
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

- [1] https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dostring
- [2] https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_load
- [3] https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_pcall